# How to run simultaneously two php files? one in background and another in foreground

Tags: php, linux, background-process

I've searched many Q/A here in SO regarding php files in background running 
but ended up asking my own .

**What I have** : I have three php files

1. **sms.php** : It  is the main file that consists some from elements(one text box for mobile number(`sim-no`) and one submit button) and a require_once which includes another php file `send_sms.php`.
2. **send_sms.php** : It is actually sending some msgs to that mobile number and between message sending there is a delay of 30s thru a fxn(`sendsms`) which is stored in `sss.php`.
3. **sss.php** : It consists that fxn(`sendsms`) which has three parameters : `countrycode`, `mobilenumber` and `message` .

**What I want** :   I want to run the php script of sending messages in the background. So , that when I enter one mobile no. and click on submit button , it will start sending the messages to that number in the background and will allow me to enter another mobile number and so on.

I've tried many things as you can see some in the code as well but couldn't make it really .

**Code**  :

**sms.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<center>
<div id="login-form">
<form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="POST">
<table align="center" width="30%" border="0">
<tr>
<td> Sim Numbers : </td>
<td> <input type = " text"   name="sim-no" id = "sim-no" placeholder = "     Please enter Mobile Number." /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="sms"   /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>

<?php
session_start();
require_once 'send_sms.php';
$_SESSION['sim-no'] = $_POST["sim-no"];
$descriptorspec = array(
 array('pipe', 'r'),               // stdin
array('file', '$_POST["sim-no"].txt', 'a'), // stdout
array('pipe', 'w'),               // stderr
);
if(($_SESSION['sim-no'] > 1000000000) && ($_SESSION['sim-no'] < 9999999999))
{
$proc = proc_open('php send_sms.php &', $descriptorspec, $pipes);
}
else
{
echo "Invalid Number !! " ; 
}
?>
```

**send_sms.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();
$sim-no = $_SESSION['sim-no'];
ignore_user_abort(1)
require_once'sss.php' ;
$countrycode=91;
echo $sim-no  ;
$mobilenumber= $sim-no ;
$message="begin030815";
$sms_status=sendsms($countrycode,$mobilenumber,$message);
sleep(30);
$message="begin123456";
$sms_status=sendsms($countrycode,$mobilenumber,$message);
sleep(30);
$message="password123456+030815";
$sms_status=sendsms($countrycode,$mobilenumber,$message);
sleep(30);
$message="itv030815+60+3600";
$sms_status=sendsms($countrycode,$mobilenumber,$message);
sleep(30);
$message="tracker030815";
$sms_status=sendsms($countrycode,$mobilenumber,$message);
sleep(30);
$message="lowbattery030815+1";
$sms_status=sendsms($countrycode,$mobilenumber,$message);
sleep(30);
$message="extpower030815+1";
$sms_status=sendsms($countrycode,$mobilenumber,$message);
sleep(30);
$message="adminip030815+110.173.191.194+6000";
$sms_status=sendsms($countrycode,$mobilenumber,$message);
sleep(30);
$message="gprs030815+1";
$sms_status=sendsms($countrycode,$mobilenumber,$message);
sleep(30);
$message="apn030815+rcomnet";
$sms_status=sendsms($countrycode,$mobilenumber,$message);
echo "Messages Sent !! " ;
?>
```

**sss.php**

Consists of function

```
<?php
function sendsms($countrycode,$mobilenumber,$message)
{
// code for message sending
}
?>
```

Comment: It would be better to create an SMS queue (e.g. using a database table) and then send pending SMS messages using a crontab. This has the advantage that you can retry if there are any failures. Each queue item can contain the number of retries and a success flag, so it can give up if a particular number cannot be sent to, or marked as sent successfully so it is not sent again.

Comment: @halfer : I'm getting 500 Internal Server Error :( . What could be the reason ? This file has been give full access rights (777) .

Comment: 500 server errors result in your PHP configuration preventing the errors being rendered to your screen (mostly for security reasons). Have a look at your server error logs, or do `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', true);` at the start of your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below concept :

when you will submit the form and send data to send_sms.php file, then fetch the data and close the connection with that file.

like below :

```
$data = $_POST;
while(ob_get_level()) ob_end_clean();
    header('Connection: close');
    ignore_user_abort();
    ob_start();
    $size = ob_get_length();
    header("Content-Length: $size");
    ob_end_flush();
    flush();
```

Comment: So ,should I add this at the top of `send_sms.php` ?

Comment: yes, if you will add above line, then connection will close with file, however that file will finished its execution.